# Rails: bad math?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got this method:

```
def progress_percentage
  (progress_index / positive_statuses.size) * 100
end
```

It's returning `0` and it should be `38.46`.

```
@lead.progress_index          # this is 5
@lead.positive_statuses.size  # this is 13
@lead.progress_percentage     # this is 0?
```

The first two values have been confirmed. What is going on? Edit: confirmed in the view here.

[image]

Comment: the duplicate doesn't cover rounding to two places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to integer math. In Ruby (like many languages) an integer divided by an integer returns an integer. In your case, 5 / 13 returns 0. If either your numerator or denominator is converted to a float before you run this operation, you will get a float in return, and the expected answer will result.

You can convert to a float using `to_f`. So `(progress_index.to_f / positive_statuses.size) * 100` should work.

Comment: Ah. Integers. Of course. Thanks for the deep answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fixnum#fdiv](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-fdiv) and [Float#round](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Float.html#method-i-round) here:

```
def progress_percentage
  ((progress_index.fdiv positive_statuses.size) * 100).round 2
end
```

as requested, returns your number rounded to two decimal places.

#### Example

```
((5.fdiv 13)*100).round 2
#=> 38.46
```